# Memory usage for application listed in Task Manager is not a good indication?

Tags: windows, memory, task-manager

I read somewhere (I think Mark's blog from sysinternals), that the memory a program takes up as listed in Task Manager is not a good way to judge where all the memory on your pc is performing.

Is this true? If so, why? I can't remember the full details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're likely talking about his "Pushing the limits" series.  You can find the articles here.

> [Physical Memory](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx)
>
> [Virtual Memory](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx)
>
> [Paged and Nonpaged Pool](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2009/03/26/3211216.aspx)

Here's an [overview](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/What-do-the-Task-Manager-memory-columns-mean) of what the Task Manager columns mean.

The main thing about memory usage displayed in task manager is it only displays one aspect.  I prefer to use Process Explorer which allows a little more customization on all the different memory statistics to display so I can compare them.  A process's memory usage can include Private Working Set as well as shared memory usage that include memory usage that is available to other process via loaded libraries.